# How do I allow a user to only run the apt-get update command with sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, security, users

I cannot figure out how to allow a user (in this case `test`) to only be able to run the `apt-get update` command with the `sudoers` file. When ever I try to add the user and then test it out it still does not allow the user to run the command.

Can someone please help me out? I have been researching this all day and can still not figure it out. I am probably typing in something wrong.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Isn't apt get update only available to sudoers ? So if a user not a sudoer the user shouldn't be able to run it

Comment: @Serg I suppose OP wants to restrict a user to only that command (no sudo priveleges).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at Andre Herman Bezerra's answer, the only problem with this is pointed out in the comments this *DOES NOT* restrict the user to update only (they can install/remove packages).

If you want to restrict a user to be able to **update only** you're better off doing the following.

**Create a group or use the `%staff` group.**

In this example, i'm choosing to use the staff user group.

**Update the `sudoers` document.**

```
export editor="vi" && sudo visudo
```

**Create a `Cmnd_Alias` which will define a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script permitted.**

```
Cmnd_Alias UPDATER_ONLY = /usr/local/bin/updater.sh
```

**You need to define how this command is permitted.**

```
# Require staff to enter password when updating.
%staff ALL= UPDATER_ONLY

# Or, password is not required, just run the updater.
%staff ALL= NOPASSWD: UPDATER_ONLY
```

**Finally, you need to create the shell.**

To prevent anyone editing the file this should be owned by root **and read-only**, or created whilst running *sudo*.

```
$ sudo echo '#!/bin/bash' >> /usr/local/bin/updater.sh
$ sudo echo 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y' >> /usr/local/bin/updater.sh
$ sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/updater.sh
```

This should look like the following:

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/updater.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60 Jan 22 08:50 /usr/local/bin/updater.sh*
```

**We're almost done!**

You need to remember to permit this privilege by adding the user to the staff group.

```
sudo usermod -aG staff the-user
```

---

If someone attempts to install something this is what they receive:

```
test-me@comp0:~$ sudo apt-get install test
[sudo] password for test-me: 
Sorry, user test-me is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get install test' as root on comp0.
```

Answer (score 9):

First, edit the `/etc/sudoers` only with `visudo`

You can set the permission to the user `joe` for `apt-get` command only adding the following line:

```
%joe your_hostname=(root):/usr/bin/apt-get
```

Once logged in as `joe`, you can check the permissions:

```
sudo -l
```

Edit: The user will be able to use apt-get update, upgrade, install, etc; since those are just flags for the apt-get command.

Comment: @andre would it not just be /usr/bin/apt-get as the update, upgrade, remove etc are merely flags for that command so if the user can run apt-get they are not restricted to the flags they can use :)

Comment: What does `(root)` mean here?